# Typescript 3.2.2 const type doesn´t match output type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am trying to implement the react-redux Todo in typescript. Link to javascript tutorial: https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react.

I now have a const getVisibleTodos of the interface getVisibilityProps. However I wish to return a TodoModel[] as these are the only ones I need.

```
interface getVisibilityProps {
    todos: TodoModel[],
    filter: vfilter

}

 const getVisibleTodos: FC<getVisibilityProps> = props => {
    switch (props.filter) {
        case VisibilityFilter.SHOW_ALL:
            return props.todos;
        case VisibilityFilter.SHOW_ACTIVE:
            return props.todos.filter(t => !t.completed);
        case VisibilityFilter.SHOW_COMPLETED:
            return props.todos.filter(t => t.completed);
        default:
            throw new Error('Unknown filter: ' + props.filter)
    }
};
```

I have tried playing around with types, these among them:

```
type visibility1 = TodoModel[] | vfilter
type visibility2 = getVisibilityProps | TodoModel[]
type visibility3 = TodoModel[] & vfilter
type visibility4 = getVisibilityProps & TodoModel[]
```

and including them to FC<> but to no avail.

**Error message:**

> TS2322: Type '(props: getVisibilityProps & { children?: ReactNode; }) => >TodoModel[]' is not assignable to type >'FunctionComponent'.
>   Type 'TodoModel[]' is missing the following properties from type >'ReactElement': type, props, key

I understand what the error is and why it happens, I just do not know the syntax in order to fix it. I´ve thought about returning the whole prop, however that seems cumbersome and not the right way to go about it.

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: It looks like you need to update your `getVisibleTodos` signature: `const getVisibleTodos: TodoModel = props:getVisibilityProps`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I´ve tried that and the error i get is the following:

> TS2740: Type '(props: getVisibilityProps) => TodoModel[]' is missing the following properties from type 'TodoModel[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 24 more.

Comment: Sorry, my bad... try: `const getVisibleTodos = (props:getVisibilityProps):TodoModel[] => ... `

Comment: Thanks, no errors this time! It seems that the FC<> part was the reason for error. Do you why and how to use FC, or when? May be obvious, but I am new to typescript and react-redux.

Comment: see my answer - use `FunctionComponent<>` wherever you're creating a functional component :-D In this case, it would be e.g. a rendered list of todo items (with a single root component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a couple of things to fix... firstly, this isn't a `FunctionComponent` because it returns a list of todos rather than a single jsx node.

Secondly, it looks like your filtering function syntax needs a tweak, specifying the return type as `TodoModel[]`:

```
interface getVisibilityProps {
    todos: TodoModel[],
    filter: vfilter

}

 const getVisibleTodos = (props: getVisibilityProps):TodoModel[] => {
    switch (props.filter) {
        case VisibilityFilter.SHOW_ALL:
            return props.todos;
        case VisibilityFilter.SHOW_ACTIVE:
            return props.todos.filter(t => !t.completed);
        case VisibilityFilter.SHOW_COMPLETED:
            return props.todos.filter(t => t.completed);
        default:
            throw new Error('Unknown filter: ' + props.filter)
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh I see now. The confusion was indeed the FC, and seems obvious now. Thanks a lot!